# What I'm doing wrong in this proxy_pass Nginx + Tomcat 7

Tags: nginx, tomcat7, proxypass

I'm trying to redirect

```
http://example2:8080/folder2/app/index.html#/home
```

to

```
https://example2.com
```

using this code:

```
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/folder2/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   }
```

and I get HTTP Status 404 - from Tomcat

There's another app on this Tomcat server which runs ok. This is the config:

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/folder1/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}
```

and is redirecting from:

```
http://example1:8080/folder1/
```

to:

```
https://example1.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the Tomcat URL with:

```
http://example2:8080/folder2/app
```

and now the proxy_pass work as expected.